# How do I make the pop-up html page visible again after hidden?

Tags: html, popup, parent-child, hidden, visible

Regarding my site: [Here](http://www.taskbasket.net/gallery/)

If you click the "Sign up" link in the top-right corner it will pop open a small html window to the front. However, if you then click the parent window it will hide the child popup window. If someone then clicks the Sign up link again, the popup remains hidden.

I'd rather it becomes visible again when someone clicks on the Sign Up link again, instead of hiding behind the parent.

Here's is the html code to create popup:

```
<a onclick="popupCenter('http://taskbasket.net/gallery/registration.html', 'myPop1',500,600);" href="javascript:void(0);">Sign Up</a>
```

Any idea how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is staying hidden is because it is in a separate window. You cannot control that from your original window. I recommend not having a popup at all. This just adds another element for the user to deal with and could be stopped by popup blockers.

Instead consider making the signup a normal link (easiest) or create a semitransparent div that overlays the rest of the page with the signup form centered in a container. If you need assistance on how to do this let us know.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, a semitransparent div sounds like the best bet, assuming it will overlay the sign-up form similar to the small pop-up now. I'll gladly accept some help if you're willing - if you need any details about my current code, the two pages of relevance are:  www.taskbasket.net/gallery and taskbasket.net/gallery/registration.html .   Thanks a lot